# Adding an item to a linked list in openCL with atomics gives mixed bytes in uint

Tags: list, opencl, atomic

I have a big problem using openCL atomics and I can't get any further.
Unfortunately I am not experienced in GPU/openCL programming. Can someone please help?

My code looks something like this:

```
typedef struct Item {
  uint ID;
  uint parentID;
  uint childID;
};

void listAdd(global struct Item* parent, global struct Item* child) {
  uint oldChildID = atomic_xchg(&parent->childID, child->ID);
  atomic_cmpxchg(&child->parentID, EMPTY, parent->ID); // line:a
  global struct Item* oldChild = getItem(oldChildID);
  // uint A = child->parentID;
  if (oldChild) {
    child->childID = oldChildID;
    atomic_cmpxchg(&oldChild->parentID, parent->ID, child->ID); // line:b
  }
  // uint B = child->parentID;
  ...
  // uint C = child->parentID;
}
```

I believe this should work, but it does not.
The problem should arise because of the use of ->parentID for the same Item at different code ("line:a" and "line:b") lines in different work items.

The function gives this:

```
A==00001011 00001101 11100010 11100101
B==00001101 00001101 11100010 11100101
C==00001101 00000110 01000100 01001110
```

A is the correct value assigned by this work item in "line:a".
C pobably comes from another work item from "line:b".
But B (and this sometimes "survives" without getting to C) is a mixture of the highest Byte (left one) and the three others.

I guess this is the result of simultaniously writing to global memory by at least two work items, but: I am using atomic functions, and I am even checking by atomic_cmpxchg() that writing is correct.

Also making the structs volatile doesn't change anything.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I solved it myself. It was a synchronization problem.